# Is it possible to reorder the NUnit tests at run-time before the execution begins?

Tags: nunit

We have quite a lot of tests that need to bypass Load Balancer in order to talk directly to a specific web server.

Each test is decorated with `TestCaseSource` attribute specifying a function that at run-time determines the list of web servers to hit.

So, if we have n tests T1, T2, ..., Tn and m Web Servers W1, W2, ..., Wm (discovered at run-time), the tests run in the following order:

```
T1W1
T1W2
...
T1Wm
T2W1
T2W2
...
T2Wm
...
TnW1
TnW2
...
TnWm
```

Now, I need them to run in a different order, namely:

```
T1W1
T2W1
...
TnW1
T1W2
T2W2
...
TnW2
...
T1Wm
T2Wm
...
TnWm
```

I understand that I can modify the test name using the TestCaseData.TestName property. But doing so would still run the child test cases together. For example, see below:

[image]

The tests `nan4dfc1app01_RegisterAndStartShiftAndEnsureInvalidBadge` and `nan4dfc1app02_RegisterAndStartShiftAndEnsureInvalidBadge` run one after another rather than:

- `nan4dfc1app01_RegisterAndStartShiftAndEnsureInvalidBadge` running with all other tests starting with `nan4dfc1app01_`
- `nan4dfc1app02_RegisterAndStartShiftAndEnsureInvalidBadge` running with all other tests starting with `nan4dfc1app02_`

So essentially, renaming the test cases does not split the child test cases. Not good for me.

So, is there a way to change the order at run-time the way I need it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to do this with a `TestCaseSourceAttribute`. All the test cases generated for a single test method are run together.

The other mechanism for grouping tests is by fixture. If you made your class a parameterized fixture and passed it the web servers using TestFixtureSourceAttribute, then you could control the order of the tests within each fixture.

You would save the passed in parameter for the fixture as an instance member and use it within every test. This is probably simpler and easier to read than what you are doing anyway, because there is only one reference to the source rather than many.

Comment: Seems to work, but generates more questions. For example - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54489945/what-is-the-nunit-test-name-template-for-the-test-fixture-arguments

Comment: Yes, it works but is not so helpful when using a runner that does not display full names of tests.